# All image src request to php script

Tags: php

I want to resize a image using server side script (eg: [Smart Image Resizer](http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/) ), so it will send request to a script called image.php

```
<img src="/image.php/media/bg.jpg?width=320&height=240"/>
```

So script will take image and its dimensions for cropping.Instead of sending request to image.php or any server scripting  why cant i pass all the img src request to image.php automatically. Using .htaccess or something?

```
<img src="/media/bg.jpg?width=320&height=240"/>
```

> ```
>  And some config should automatically take it in and pass this
> ```
>
> to your image resizer script and
>   return the image result. Is it
>   possible?

Thanks

Comment: It's possible, but this will be very resource heavy, as *every* time you load the image it'll have to be re-generated on the server. Are you sure this is the best way to proceed? (I'd have thought at the *very* least you'd want to check for a cached version of the image at the same size.)

Comment: so why can't you  just put a `.htaccess` inside the `/media/` folder that redirects image requests to image.php?

Comment: Just a note, it's strongly recommended to still include the width/height attributes of img tags to decrease load time and help with browser layout during the absence of content (Especially now that the image is being generated and not just served.

Comment: Yes exactly. I have placed it into media directoy rewrite rule. Will it make any problem?

Comment: @Ela That is exactly what I would do. Just put a `.htaccess` inside the media directory and have it redirect all requests there to a php script. Then I would have the php script get the requested dimensions, check to see if there is a file that exists for that image in those dimensions (cached copy) and if so, display that, if not, resize and save to cache.

Comment: @Jonathan thanks for your trick. Its really good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i have got it.

I added this line in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^media/(.*).jpg$ image.php?src=$1 [L]
```

so when ever request comes into media directory with jpg extension all those will be passed to the image.php

Am i right? I ma trying this way.

Answer (score 1):

By automatically, do you mean on page load?

If so, i would use jQuery ajax to send the img to the image.php and display the returned image onto the page. Or am i completely misunderstanding your request?

Comment: No no, I want the automatic request to a php script. Ajax calls will take time after image loaded in client side. I have added my update in answer. check it