# Laravel filter img request

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is there any way to filter a request for images. Like there is the possibility to filter a route?
I would like to load a class for every img request.

I know about the [.htaccess possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617572/all-image-src-request-to-php-script) but I would like to not touch it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default .htaccess file only redirects to Laravel's index.php file when a real file or directory doesn't exist at the requested path. So when you have a link pointing to the direct file, this isn't something you can do without modification.

However, you could point to a virtual directory with a defined route, that in turn points to the real file location.

Example:

Virtual-
/img/file.png

Real-
/assets/img/file.png

Comment: Yep you are right. There is no way around the htacces. Makes sense because otherwise every request for a picture would boot the app right?